# Waiting for a single event in OpenCL

Tags: c, opencl

I am writing a OpenCL program in which multiple kernels are being called on multiple devices.  After I have enqueued all of the kernels I would like to wait until any of them has finished and then enqueue work for that device afterwords.

For instance, I have devices A and B and each of them have a kernel.  If A finishes first, I want to enqueue a new kernel in it after doing some work.  If B finishes first I want to enqueue a new kernel for it after doing some work.  I'm looking for something like a `clWaitForAnyEvent` which will return after any event passed in has finished.

Looking at the spec, I see a `clWaitForEvents` method, but it seems that it will wait for all of the event to finish before continuing, and I want to continue after one event (and need to know which event finished).

The options I can think of right now are:

1. Busy-wait using `clGetEventInfo` to test for event completion.
2. Multi-thread having one thread for each event (will only need a few threads, but am using the CPU as one of the devices)
3. Missed something in the specification and there is actually a method that does this for me.

Any suggestions of how to proceed or something that I am missing?

Thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your answer is 3.

`clWaitForEvents` will do exactly what you want.  Let's say you have a command queue for a device which we will call `klee_dev`.  You can enqueue work on klee_dev like this:

```
cl_event event;
cl_int status = clEnqueueNDRangeKernel(queue_for_klee_dev, ..., &event);

/* enqueue other work on other devices, perhaps even klee_dev */

clWaitForEvents(1, &event);
```

The call to `clWaitForEvents` will block until the work you enqueued on `klee_dev`'s command queue completes.  It will *not* wait for other work to complete; just the work specified by enqueue call associated with that one event.

EDIT:

I misunderstood the original question, which was clarified below.  The OP was asking if there is a method in the CL specification that, given a *set* of events, will block until *any one* of the events completes.  There is currently no such method.

EDIT, again:

You could register a callback method for each event with `clSetEventCallback`.  Within the callback, you can query the event with `clGetEventInfo` to find out what command queue was associated with the event.

That gives you what you require, I think: notification of *any* event completion, and the ability to find out what command queue is associated with the event.

Comment: Yes, but suppose I have 4 queues, and enqueue 4 different kernels on them.  I would like to wait until one of them finishes (any one) and want to know which queue it is from.  Using this method I would be waiting for only one unit of work.

Comment: Ah, I see.  I think you need to rephrase your original question, then.  As written, it's not clear.  Consider incorporating your comment above into your question.

Comment: I interpreted the question exactly like James did. KLee1, you need to rephrase your question; it is very misleading, especially the part where you say, "I would like to wait until one of them has finished..."

Comment: Okay, I will edit my question to make this more clear.  Thanks!

Comment: KLee1, I revised my answer to better address your real issue.